# Java Input File wont print

Tags: java, file, input

I was working on an assignment for which I need to print the average of 3 different sets of scores from an inputted file in java. The average has to be rounded to 2 decimal places. I tried creating the scanners so the decimals from the input file could be added and averaged out, but when I click to run, netbeans just runs and nothing prints out. I do not get an error either.  Any tips on how I can get this to run would be appreciated.

The input file contents:
7.88 6.44 5.66 3.44
7.50 9.80 4.33 2.31
8.99 7.62 3.67 4.39

``Here is the code(all necessary imports are already imported)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Gym.in"));

        double Number = sc.nextFloat();
        {
            NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
            fmt.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            fmt.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

            Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("Gym.in"));
            int maxIndx = -1;
            String text[] = new String[100];
            while (sf.hasNext())
                ;
            {
                maxIndx++;
                text[maxIndx] = sf.nextLine();
                System.out.println(text[maxIndx]);
            }
            sf.close();

            String answer;
            double sum;
            double average;

            for (int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++) {
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text[j]);
                Scanner sg = new Scanner(text[j]);
                System.out.println(text[j]);

                Scanner ss = new Scanner(text[j]);
                sum = 0;
                average = sum / 10;
                answer = "For Competitor #1, the average is: ";

                while (sc.hasNext()) {
                    double i = sc.nextDouble();
                    answer = answer + i;
                    sum = sum + i;
                }

                answer = answer + average;
                System.out.println(answer);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing to do is fix your code indentation - it's *very* hard to read while it's all over the place like this.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: Netbeans allows you to run it step-by-step. Just see where the execution hangs.

Comment: post the error message

Comment: at the end what is the value of maxIndx? I guess it's still -1 and your file isn't read properly

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with this code - one is that you expect `'.'` as the decimal point character, but in my locale it is `','`, so the first thing I got was an `java.util.InputMismatchException`.

Anyway, the reason why your code seems not to do anything is these lines:

```
 while (sf.hasNext())
             ;
```

This is effectively an endless loop. You are looping while your scanner has more tokens to deliver, but you never retrieve the next token. So `hasNext()` will return `true` forever.

If you remove the `;` then your code runs through. I have not verified the results though.

---

You also need to rework your average calculation: with your code, your average will always stay `0.0`:

```
sum = 0;
average = sum / 10;
...
answer = answer + average;
System.out.println(answer);
```

I am also not sure why you want to devide the sum by 10 - this should probably be 12 in your case (assumed that "each set of scores" is one line in your input file). All in all, your approach is not too bad - you basically have to remove some unnecessary code and put the statements from the second loop in the correct order :)

```
for (int j = 0; j <= maxIndx; j++) {
    double sum = 0;
    double average = 0;

    Scanner ss = new Scanner(text[j]);
    String answer = "For Competitor #1, the average is: ";

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        double i = sc.nextDouble();
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    average = sum / 12; // better use number of tokens read instead of hard coded 12

    answer = answer + average;
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

Finally, you do not need to read each line into a `String` array - just read one line and process it immediately. This saves memory and avoids `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s when there are more than 100 lines in the file. I let this up to you as an excercise :)

Comment: Looks like you were right, the semicolon was the main problem! I got the code reorganized and fixed with the answer I wanted printing out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove the ; after the while (sf.hasNext())

change

```
while (sf.hasNext())
;
{
```

into

```
while (sf.hasNext())
{
```